# Problems with android app with long time activity

Tags: android, time, long-integer

I am a novice developer and I have a question: i create an app that should remain open and active for a long time with display on. It could create problems of any type like crash when load internal assets image?
Thank you.

Comment: any more details this seems a little vague

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems unless you screwed something up (created some memory leaks). With garbage collector you shouldn't have problems with keeping memory usage at reasonable levels.